# Resolving negation of multiple OR statements in a conditional

Tags: php, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I'm having bit of trouble getting my head around negation of multiple OR statements.

In the case of AND, let's say I have the following:

```
$a = 'john';
$b = 'mark';
$c = 'luke';

if(!($a == 'john' && $b == 'mark' && $c == 'luke'))
{
    echo "Not All Apostles";
}
```

It's clear that there is no echo/output because all the conditions match. Also, the negation is somewhat easy to understand. In other words, if I was using `1` for true and `0` for false, the condition can only match if it resolves to only `111`, so with the negation, the condition is true if it is NOT `111` i.e. negation matches if I have `101`, `100`, `001`, etc.

So what happens when I have the following:

```
if(!($a == 'john' || $b == 'david' || $c == 'luke'))
{
    echo "???";
}
```

Without the negation, it will resolve to true if [using the numeric notation introduced earlier] the condition resolves to anything except `000` i.e. there must be at least one match for the condition to resolve to true if the negation is not present.

So what exactly happens with the negation present?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question, but you get TRUE for anything else than `000` with the negation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws  `not(A || B) ~ not(A) && not(B)`. Also `not(A && B) ~ not(A) || not(B)`

Comment: @Rizier123 I thought it would be TRUE for anything other than `000` WITHOUT the negation i.e. only if there is at least one match it will be TRUE without the negation?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused with bitwise vs boolean comparison:

You're using boolean comparison `&&` and `||` not the bitwise operators `&` and `|`.

Every comparison in you conditional evaluates to `true` or `false`:

So:

```
if(!($a == 'john' && $b == 'mark' && $c == 'luke'))
{
   echo "Not All Apostles";
}
```

Is actually:

```
if(!(true && true && true))
{
   echo "Not All Apostles";
}
```

Which is `if(false)`

Your second example:

```
if(!(true || true || true))
{ 
     echo "???";
  }
```

Becomes

```
if(!($a == 'john' || $b == 'mark' || $c == 'luke'))
{ 
     echo "???";
  }
```

Which is also

```
if(!(true))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Edited the question to make one of the conditions false. So I guess that would be `if(true || true || false)` which is `if(true)`, and therefore `if(!true)` with negation. So does that mean with OR conditionals, negation is logically equivalent to AND conditionals without negation?

Comment: In basic Boolean algebra this is the equivalency between AND and OR :  `A and B  = !( !A or !B)`, someone commented about that in your OP

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did a small diagram to work it all out. Cheers.